# During start up, how can load remote image?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I success to load the image and JSON with NSURLSession.
But I want to load these files during Start up.(When launchImage is viewed, file is loaded and launchImage is disappeared then remote-image is shown up) How can I do this?

Comment: What part of that is causing you a problem?  (I assume you know about `applicationDidFinishLaunching`....)

Answer (score -1):

Although yes, a library is not always necessary, I do find [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to be very handy in this case. Import `AFNetworking.h` and `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` and you can make requests like this for images from a remote server. After creating an imageView you can load the image into a UIImageView using a request like this.

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://image.url"]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"]
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , UIImage *image ){
                                    NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %d", [response statusCode]);
                                }
                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                    NSLog(@"failed loading: %@", error);
                                }
     ];
```

Using the NSHTTPURLResponse you can also get the image and do whatever caching you would like or save it to a directory.

Edit: This question was phrased in a way difficult to understand. Although this may not directly answer the askers question, it is relevant to the question's title and could help someone who searches for it in the future.

Comment: Please give reason for down voting.